# mockito 'You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.' with java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

use powermockito

```
 @Test
    public void searchAll() throws IOException {
        CustomerQuery param = new CustomerQuery();

        MultiSearchResponse response = PowerMockito.mock(MultiSearchResponse.class);
        PowerMockito.when(esClient.msearch(any(MultiSearchRequest.class), any(RequestOptions.class))).thenReturn(response);

        CustomerSearchResult searchResult = service.searchAll(param);
        assertNotNull(searchResult);
    }
```

then, it tell me

```
You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
```

I read this article
[Mockito 'Misplaced argument detected here' in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32909129/mockito-misplaced-argument-detected-here-in-java/32909234)
But can't solve,
What am I supposed to do?
thanks .

Comment: Is `esClient` a mock?

Comment: you have to create a mock of `esClient` just as you did for `MultiSearchResponse`, before you define behaviors on the mock object.

Comment: Welcome to StackOwerflow! **---** Just for the records: from the snipped of code presented I cannot see why you are using *PowerMock*  rather that just *Mockito*. However: If you need *PowerMock* it is usually a surrender to bad design, which means your code is not "clean" following the SOLID principles, in particular *Open/Closed Principle*, *Inversion of Control*, and *Dependency Injection*.

Comment: Problem solved.
esClient.msearch() is final function.