# InvalidUseOfMatchersException while stubbing in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I have a Java method signature like this:

```java
public Resource generatePDF(
  List<InvoiceReportEntity> invoices,
  String labelerCd,
  InvoiceContactEntity contact,
  CalculatedInvoiceAmount calculatedInvoice,
  InvoicePaymentEntity invoicePaymentsAddress,
  List <InvoiceReportPpaEntity> allQuartersInvoicePpaList,
  BigDecimal currQtrInterestAmt,
  List<InvoicePpaInterest> intAmt,
  Integer invoiceYearQtr
)
```

Here is my unit test written in Groovy:

```groovy
def '10.Export PDF with valid id'() {
    given:'Valid id'
    def invoiceIds = ['AL4-00008-20192']
    def types = [ExportType.PDF] as ExportType[]

    and:
    def mockInvoicePDFProcessor = mock(InvoicePDFProcessor)

    when(
      mockInvoicePDFProcessor.generatePDF(
        any(List.class),
        anyString(),
        any(InvoiceContactEntity.class),
        any(CalculatedInvoiceAmount.class),
        any(InvoicePaymentEntity.class),
        any(List.class),
        any(BigDecimal.class),
        any(List.class),
        any(Integer.class)
      )
    )
    .thenReturn(mock(Resource));
    invoiceController.setPdfProcessor(mockInvoicePDFProcessor)

    when: 'Retrieve results based on invoice header id'
    def response = invoiceController.exportInvoiceData(
      types, invoiceIds,
      mock(HttpServletResponse)
    )

    then: 'response received'
    response.getStatusCode().value() == 200
    response.hasBody()
}
```

This test passes when run individually, but when the entire test cases are run, I get this exception

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:
-> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
-> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
-> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
-> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
    when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use
Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
    at 10.Export PDF with valid id(InvoiceControllerSpec.groovy:222)**
```

I have used .class to all the classes used above, still the same result.
I have searched for similar errors, but unfortunately the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32909129/mockito-misplaced-argument-detected-here-in-java/32909234) doesn't work for me:

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not using Spock's mocking system? It's one of the major features of the framework. (You also seem not to be doing things idiomatically in general, such as putting the expected value first [also idiomatic in JUnit] or using `response.statusCode`. Finally, passing the `HttpServletResponse` as a controller parameter is a code smell, though it can be justified if you need to do something like a streaming return of a generated PDF.)

Comment: Welcome to SO. I have just massively reformatted code and question for readability and removed the test code you posted twice. BTW, in addition to what was said before, IMO a method with 9 parameters is a code smell from a clean code perspective. Chances are that your method under test does too much and/or consists of spaghetti code which should be factored out into smaller, maintainable and testable methods.